# Neo4j WARN Config file [D:\neo4j\neo4j.conf] does not exist

Tags: neo4j

I followed the steps introduced by neo4j website(https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#tutorials 7.2) to deploy neo4j cluster version. But when I wanted to start neo4j by command 'neo4j console'. It showed 'WARN Config file [D:\neo4j\neo4j.conf] does not exist.' Can you help me with this?

Comment: Well, does it exist? Besides, it doesn't seem to conform to the organisation of the distribution, where `neo4j.conf` is located under the `conf` folder.

Comment: The file [D:\neo4j\neo4j.conf] doesn't exist. I don't know why neo4j want to find config file here. And there is a `neo4j.conf` file in conf folder. Besides, when I did same things in a linux machine, the problem didn't show again.